# Commission an animation to explain a scientific concept?

Tags: graphics

I have a particularly difficult scientific concept, which, with the use of an animation, I think I could make very clear. I have some experience making little movies from piecing together figure snapshots, but in this case I lack the skills (and time) to assemble a quality animation. Is anyone aware of a website, resource, or company that will assemble movies for academic purposes? I've looked around but haven't found anything reasonable (in price, or with experience producing scientific-quality movies).

An example: an animation showing an EKG trace, and a diagram of a beating heart. Each beat moves the heart and shows up on the EKG, so you can see how the two are related.

Comment: Interesting idea. What price range do you have in mind?

Comment: Depends. If my PI goes for it, probably up to a few hundred dollars. If it's out of pocket, probably 100 max. But I was really hoping someone would point me to a project bid type place where interested people could assess what it might cost, and how much they'd pay to do it. Something like freelancer.com or getacoder.com.

Comment: You could find some explanatory videos on YouTube that use animations, try to find out who did the animation, and contact the animator.

Comment: @vector07 I am not expert, but that seems very low for professional animation.

Comment: Isn't this what PhD students are for? (only half-joking). For such little money, I suspect your best option is to run a competition with your few hundred dollars as prize.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers - I'm not joking when I say the following - please turn your comment into an answer! The last sentence is a great advice.

Comment: My immediate thought is PHD comics ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With such a small budget (less than 1000 US dollars), you're unlikely to be able to commission professional work.

You have three options that I can see.

1. You might be able to find someone who's just trying to get established as a provider of such services, who might be willing to do the work in exchange for publicity which you'd have to drum up. Your project, and your department, would have to be seen as endorsing this person's services. That can all be rather tricky. If you're lucky, one of your recently-finishing students might be trying to build their business in this area.
2. You might be able to learn the skills yourself, or get someone in your team to do so. Some data analysis packages do have the means to create animations from sequences of charts - Matlab has this, and I'd expect its peers such as Mathematica to be able to do that too.
3. The sort of thing that's been done in a department closely related to the one I work in, is to hold a competition, with the prize being the funds you've got available. It can be open to anyone, or to staff and students, or just to students: that choice may not make a big difference - most of your submissions might come from students anyway. Be careful with the competition terms and conditions: pay close attention to the ownership of the intellectual property of submissions (to ensure you can use submissions without restriction); and with how the prize is described (because of potential tax implications). Your library staff may be able to help with the first of those two issues, and the finance team should be able to help with the second.

What you're after - the skill of creating high-quality data visualisations - is just the sort of skill that we look to encourage and develop in our students, so I'd have no qualms in running this as a competition for the students. The tricky question is around extrinsic versus intrinsic motivation: should they be doing it for money, or for the intrinsic reward of developing excellent data visualisation. You might want to discuss that with the tutor who takes lead responsibility for the students' academic development. It will depend, to an extent, on how close your subject matter is to their areas of study.

Comment: This is the kind of thing, if I weren't defending in 4 weeks, I'd definitely try to do myself. I've made toy animations in Matlab and I've played with flash before. But I *know* it would take me a week or two to make this--and even then, it wouldn't be as slick! I'm just a little surprised there isn't a service, say, to link undergraduate students in the arts to poor academics in need of quality figures (or animations).

Comment: Why do you think that those undergraduate arts students who are able to produce quality work should be willing to work for a week or two for a couple hundred dollars, i.e., less than minimum wage?

Comment: Surely if they're talented, they *could* get a real job, but they're in school... I suspect the opportunity to apply that talent in a discrete project that will actually get used and seen by others is rare.